# How many people were executed during the reign of Henry VIII?

Tags: england, tudor-period, henry-viii

I've read something from a few online sources that I don't quite trust (probably because I'm British), but I suspect the reality of the suggestion is in fact highly likely. Going on the data we have from the French Revolution, where a conservative estimate puts the death toll of the Terror at 40,000, I think I'd possibly agree with (or hand credibility to) this figure of [57,000 people killed by Henry VIII](https://www.history.co.uk/article/the-killer-king-how-many-people-did-henry-viii-execute#:%7E:text=It%20is%20estimated%20that%20during,up%20and%20down%20the%20country.) (mostly) during the Reformation.

I think it highly probable given the impact the Reformation had on the daily lives of Catholics in Britain (i.e. literally everyone) and I'm basing in part on the structural similarity here with the French Revolution, which sought the total eradication of religion from France. I suspect many of the people killed in the Terror of the Revolution were clergy, many would also have been dissenters; i.e. ordinary people with strong religious and anti-revolutionary convictions. And given the persistence of Catholicism in England following the Reformation, I suspect it's also likely that many in England at the time of the Reformation were deeply incensed by Henry's rampant demolition of British Catholicism. It would have affected people's everyday lives and profoundly shaken their culture.

The above linked article at the History channel site covers a lot of individuals executions, but seems lacking on sources supporting the overall figure of 57,000. I'd like to know about any sources you feel confirms or denies this claim. Thank you very much.

Comment: You may want to add paragraphs and a summary. Apart from the title, I don't really see a question.

Comment: If you wish to debate information figures from *'a few online sources'*, we need you to cite them so they can be evaluated. Otherwise we may just end up citing information back that you have already read.  You might look at our meta discussion concerning questions which ['doubt the existing narrative'](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote/922#:~:text=That%20said%2C%20unless%20you%20have%20a%20reason%20to%20doubt%20the%20fact%20in%20question%2C%20why%20are%20you%20asking%3F).

Comment: Ok, I've tried to find the sources, but for whatever reason can't get through to the webpage. On the subject of 'sources' and their, often, deep unreliability, and history's obsession with appearing empirical, I have only this to say: consider the sheer volume of primary source material clearly destroyed during the Dissolution of the Monasteries.

Comment: @SamCottle, probably your third-to-last sentence was meant to be that your find it very _likely_ that atrocities beyond slavery were committed? I'm just guessing...

Comment: @Jos We could always start there if you like.

Comment: @paulgarrett you guessed correctly, I am very tired.

Comment: I wish I could find again the reference of a guy who counted still surviving priest holes in English manors. The number is surprisingly high, and they were not needed if everybody were anglican... I also wonder how many more were demolished or lost with time.

Comment: Luiz thank you for that. I thought about this earlier, why even bother building them unless priests were being routinely executed following the Dissolution of the Monasteries? If that was happening afterwards, I shudder to think what was during it. And yeah, I bet the number would have been very high, people don't give up their religion with, it would seem, basically zero fuss.

Comment: I've made an edit to fix the "wall of text" problem, and a few very minor grammar issues. It still needs a good thorough editing, perhaps by someone with the deft touch of Sweeney Todd. Paragraph 3 seems particularly irrelevant.

Comment: I have tried to do the requested *trimming down' of this question to make it more concise. @SamCottle note that you can revert the edits made if you feel it is excessive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into this if find two numbers are often repeated concerning this topic, a low estimate of 56,000 and a high range of 72,000 or more. These numbers appear across the web at various history focused sites, and a few recent books. The question concerning the validity of these claims has even popped up on other question sites like [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tudorhistory/comments/hv4rfr/henry_viii_had_between_57000_and_72000_people/) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-people-did-King-Henry-Vlll-execute).

But to start to find anything close to sources for these figures we have to go back over 100 years, to a book on *The History of the Criminal Law of England*, vol 1 (1883), by [James Stephen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fitzjames_Stephen)

In his book Stephen makes some calculations to extrapolate a possible number of executions across England based on the percentage of sentenced individuals which were actually executed in some select locations. [Page 468](https://archive.org/details/cu31924069583767/page/468/mode/2up?view=theater):

> If  the   average  number  of    executions  in  each county  was
> only  twenty,  or  a  little  more  than  a  quarter  of  the number
> of  capital  sentences  in  Devonshire  in   1598,  this would  make
> 800   executions  a  year  in  the   forty  English counties.     The
> number  of  executions  was  notoriously  very great.

*I believe* this little calculation is *the basis* for the 56,000 number bantered about the Web. But the numbers don't add up yet. If we calculate the 800 execution per year, over the 36 year span of Henry VIII, we only get 28,800 executions. To get to 56,000 we need more.

Another work, from 1904, discussing the use of the death penalty in England, gives us a source for the higher end figure of 72,000 and provides the *more* we need based on Stephens number. From [The Humane Review, Volume 4, Issues 13-16(emphasis mine)](https://books.google.com/books?id=IycKAAAAIAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=henry%20Viii%20%20executions%20%20per%20year&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> Until well within the last century hundreds of people were sentenced
> to death every year in England I do not know that the French during
> the later Middle Ages were particularly scrupulous in the matter of
> executions yet if we may believe Sir John Fortescue Chancellor of
> Henry VII they were a long way behind us for he says that there were
> more persons executed for robbery in England during one year of Henry
> VII s reign than in France in seven years **Hollinshed the Elizabethan
> historian** alleged that during Henry VIII s reign there were upwards of
> ***72,000 persons hanged as thieves and vagabonds*** This amazing total
> gives an average of something thing like 1,900 executions per annum As
> there were no complete statistics at that period it is possible that
> this number may have been exaggerated yet without doubt it
> approximated very closely to the truth because when we come to a few
> years later to the reign of Elizabeth we have unimpeachable
> documentary evidence which shows that the number of executions was
> very great It has been calculated by no less a man than the late Mr
> Justice Stephen that after making all possible deductions for error
> the executions ***could not have been less than 800 a year*** The
> probability is that they were considerably in excess of 800 there is
> even the *possibility that they were actually **double that number*** And
> this it must be remembered was at a time when the population of the
> whole country was less by 1.94 millions than that of Greater London at
> the present day.

(the footnote says: The population of England is given as 4,800,000 in 1600)

Here we have an *estimate* that *double* the 800 per year was a *possibility*. 1600 per year over the 36 year reign of Henry VII=57,600. This is how I believe the 57000 number was arrived at. It is a *doubling* of Stephens original figure of 800 per year.

(For those interested in the 72000 figure it is discussed in an article entitled  [Two Myths in the History of Capital Punishment](https://scholarlycommons.law.northwestern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4814&context=jclc) from the Journal of Criminal Law and Criminology.)

Comment: The numbers in the last quoted sentence look very wrong. The current population of Greater London is about 9 million so if the population of the whole country was "less by 194 millions" then the population at the time would be -185 million. I'm not sure what a negative population would look like but I'd guess the country would have to be very empty.

Comment: @KillingTime Yep, OCR dropped the decimal.  Good catch.

Comment: Christ, then add in the deaths due to the Reformation (dissenters/former monks and nuns) and I shudder to think what the true death toll was. 100,000+(?). Advancing the national agenda on the one hand, soaking us in blood on the other. There's a debate we're not having in UK history classes.

Comment: This is very good historising.